# Adding a month to an input date in unix

Tags: unix, shell, script, ksh

I need to write a script that asks user for an input date. Then I need to add a month to that date or at least 30 days.

Example:

Date: 2009-05-12

I need to get 2009-06-12

this code is not working:

`$date -d "2009-05-12 + 1 month" "+%Y-%m-%d"`

My OS is AIX, I am using korn shell.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your script a little bit.

```
$ date -d "2009-05-12 1 month" +%Y-%m-%d
```

You dont have to write a + to add a month but if you remove time you have to write a -. Also you don't need "" to change the format of the date.

Comment: I got this:

date: Not a recognized flag: d
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]